# Vorpal.js: output full command list

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, vorpal.js

I'm looking through the Wiki and I find info on how to make Vorpal output a full command list from the myapp$ prompt. It appears Vorpal will only output help for individual commands, but the Wiki on Github says there should be a way to output the whole lot in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vorpal has a built-in `help` command, which when run from the prompt will output all commands that have been registered and have not had the `.hidden` method run on them.

```
$ help
... shows all commands
```

Programatically, there currently isn't a public method for getting all of the commands, but you can use `vorpal.commands` access this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if this answer my question or not yet, really, but it's useful to be reminded of the .hidden command. I'll have a ponder :).

Comment: Ah. Could you please try to clarify your question with a little more data?

Comment: What data do you need? I think if I want to be able to output the full command list, I will need to create that code myself, is that right?

Comment: Oh - do you mean the help command, with the exception of showing even hidden commands?

Comment: It would be nice to have some sample code on the github that includes all the available pre-written commands together, so when you type 'help' it'll output absolutely everything. I can do this for you tomorrow if you like.

Comment: `help` and `exit` are the only built-in Vorpal commands. I must be missing something...

Comment: I mean if I take all the example code you've put in the wiki and put it all together as one example, the user can just bung that into a js file, run help and it'll output all the pre-written functions, giving them an idea of what Vorpal.js is capable of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92639/discussion-between-peter-david-carter-and-dthree).

Comment: K - answered you in chat!